# QueryMultiple Result Set Order Changed

Tags: c#, dapper

I am executing a stored procedure using `QueryMultiple` to return multiple sets of data.

```
var gridReader = db.QueryMultiple("sp", 
                                  parameters, 
                                  commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

I can very easily get each set given I know the order they will come back in.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Set1;
SELECT * FROM dbo.Set2;
SELECT * FROM dbo.Set3;
```

```
var set1 = gridReader.Read<Set1>();
var set2 = gridReader.Read<Set2>();
var set3 = gridReader.Read<Set3>();
```

However, I am in a situation where the order they will come back in may change. Another developer could decide to change the order for whatever reason. The stored procedure now becomes this:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Set1;
SELECT * FROM dbo.Set3;
SELECT * FROM dbo.Set2;
```

How can I handle this?

My initial attempt was to iterate each grid, checking the column names. This seemed to work well at first, but I wasn't able to figure out how to then project the grid into a class, besides manually setting each field. The main reason I'm using Dapper is so it can do this for me.

```
while (true)
{
    var grid = gridReader.Read();
    IDictionary<string, object> row = grid.FirstOrDefault();

    if (row == null)
        break;

    if (row.Keys.Contains("Set1_UniqueColumnName"))
    {
        // Need something like grid.Read<Set1>();
    }
    else if (row.Keys.Contains("Set2_UniqueColumnName")) { }
    else if (row.Keys.Contains("Set3_UniqueColumnName")) { }
}
```

My second idea was to read each grid into a class, check the unique fields of the class for nulls/default values, and trying the next class if the test failed. This obviously won't work though. `.Read()` will return the *next* grid of results. This solution would require me to be able to read the same grid over and over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Davmos's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45584549/3711928) pointed me in the right direction. Needed to use a combination of ADO.NET and Dapper. Essentially use ADO.NET to retrieve and iterate through the data, but use Dapper to parse the rows into my objects. Note the use of `FieldCount` in the while loop in case a result set actually does return 0 rows. We want it to move on to the next result set, not break out of the loop.

```
Set1 set1 = null;
var set2 = new List<Set2>();
Set3 set3 = null;

using (var command = new SqlCommand("sp", conn))
{
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
    command.Connection.Open();

    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.FieldCount > 0)
        {
            var set1Parser = reader.GetRowParser<Set1>();
            var set2Parser = reader.GetRowParser<Set2>();
            var set3Parser = reader.GetRowParser<Set3>();

            var isSet1 = HasColumn(reader, "Set1_UniqueColumnName");
            var isSet2 = HasColumn(reader, "Set2_UniqueColumnName");
            var isSet3 = HasColumn(reader, "Set3_UniqueColumnName");

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (isSet1)
                {
                    set1 = set1Parser(reader);
                }
                else if (isSet2)
                {
                    set2.Add(set2Parser(reader));
                }
                else if (isSet3)
                {
                    set3 = set3Parser(reader);
                }
            }

            reader.NextResult();
        }
    }
}
```

```
public static bool HasColumn(IDataReader reader, string columnName)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        if (reader.GetName(i).Equals(columnName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Dapper provides an `IDataReader.GetRowParser` extension method that enables type switching per row. From the Dapper docs [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper#type-switching-per-row)...

> Usually you'll want to treat all rows from a given table as the same
>   data type. However, there are some circumstances where it's useful to
>   be able to parse different rows as different data types. This is where
>   IDataReader.GetRowParser comes in handy.
>
> Imagine you have a database table named "Shapes" with the columns: Id,
>   Type, and Data, and you want to parse its rows into Circle, Square, or
>   Triangle objects based on the value of the Type column.

```
var shapes = new List<IShape>();
using (var reader = connection.ExecuteReader("select * from Shapes"))
{
    // Generate a row parser for each type you expect.
    // The generic type <IShape> is what the parser will return.
    // The argument (typeof(*)) is the concrete type to parse.
    var circleParser = reader.GetRowParser<IShape>(typeof(Circle));
    var squareParser = reader.GetRowParser<IShape>(typeof(Square));
    var triangleParser = reader.GetRowParser<IShape>(typeof(Triangle));

    var typeColumnIndex = reader.GetOrdinal("Type");

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        IShape shape;
        var type = (ShapeType)reader.GetInt32(typeColumnIndex);
        switch (type)
        {
            case ShapeType.Circle:
                shape = circleParser(reader);
                break;
            case ShapeType.Square:
                shape = squareParser(reader);
                break;
            case ShapeType.Triangle:
                shape = triangleParser(reader);
                break;
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        shapes.Add(shape);
    }
}
```

You'll need to get access to the `IDataReader` that the `GridReader` wraps or change your code to use the good old-fashioned ADO.NET `SqlConnection` & `SqlCommand` objects like this...

```
using (command = new SqlCommand("sp", connection))
{
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);

    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // read row columns
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction! I figured I was going to need `GetRowParser` somehow but I couldn't quite figure it out. Combining that with a SqlDataReader did the trick.